# Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, meteor, sass, libc++

I'm trying to run [a Meteor.js app](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope) on my machine and getting this error which I assume means I need to get [libc++.1.dylib](http://libcxx.llvm.org/index.html), but I wonder if there's something else I'm missing (libc++ install is a pain):

```
While loading plugin `fourseven:scss` from package `fourseven:scss`:
module.js:356:32:
dlopen(/Users/m/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.1.0.0.wp4tvk++os.linux.x86_64+os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.fourseven:scss.os.osx.x86_64/npm/fourseven:scss/node_modules/node-sass/bin/darwin-x64-v8-3.14/binding.node,
1): Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
Referenced from:
/Users/m/.meteor/packages/fourseven_scss/.1.0.0.wp4tvk++os.linux.x86_64+os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.fourseven:scss.os.osx.x86_64/npm/fourseven:scss/node_modules/node-sass/bin/darwin-x64-v8-3.14/binding.node
Reason: image not found
```

Full error: http://pastebin.com/y452BeDj

Is it just this dependency I need, or might there be an other, easier way?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem trying to run Meteor temporarily on another machine while Apple fix my Macbook, I think the problem lies in the fact that there is not C compiler installed, something that should happen during the install of Xcode.